# How To Increase Push Notification Limit of 10/day For Google Assistant

Tags: push-notification, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

As per this link (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/best-practices-limits) there is a limit on number of push notifications that can be sent to user.

How can I increase the push notification limit for google assistant?
Is the increase possible during free trial subscription ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to send a lot of notifications. Can you elaborate a little on your use case for why you want to send so many notifications to each user?

Comment: The intention of the limit is likely to avoid notification spam for the user. Perhaps it might be wise to consider why you want to send so many notifications and consider ways to be less annoying to your users.